# TransactionScope with MQ - read and write message

Tags: vb.net, ibm-mq, transactionscope

I have a piece of vb.net code that reads a message from an MQ queue and writes it to another queue.

It does this in a transaction (`using New TransactionScope()`), so if the write fails the read will be rolled back.

The problem is, the Transaction only seems to commit once I close the .net program.

Using MQ Explorer, I see the message move, and then it shows "`Uncommitted Messages: Yes`" in the queue status (and the message remains on the new queue), until the .net program closes - at which point the message is read from the queue by another program (IIB).

So, it seems to me that the `TransactionScope` isn't being disposed; but I can't think why not.

Here's the relevant code:

WPF calls a command when a button is pressed, which calls the following method (simplified):

```
' MQMessageDetails is just a data-storage class for message data
Friend Function MoveMessages(messages as IEnumerable(of MQMessageDetails))
    For Each msg in messages
       Try
        Using ts As New TransactionScope()
            success = WriteMessage(msg, "Q.OUT")
            success = success and ReadMessage(msg)
            If success Then
                ts.Complete()
            End If
        End Using
       Catch ....
       End Try
    Next
End Function
```

And Here's what I see in MQ explorer:

```
**Before program start**
Q.IN - depth 2, no uncommitted messages
Q.OUT - depth 0, no uncommitted messages

**Move button clicked**
Q.IN - depth 1, 1 uncommitted message
Q.OUT - depth 1, 1 uncommitted message

**Program closed**
Q.IN - depth 1, no uncommitted messages
Q.OUT - depth 0, no uncommitted messages <- the message was read by another program
```

Comment: Have you tried issuing an mq commit in your If success ... clause ?

Comment: No, I didn't think I had to do that because I am using a transactionscope (so it should handle it automatically?)

Comment: What version of MQ client are you using?

Comment: 7.5.0.6 I believe. I have no control over the environment so I can't install anything (but I can provide dlls with the exe)

Comment: I.e. once the Using block ends, it should dispose the transactionscope and commit, right?

Comment: Using a manual commit on the queue manager does the trick. But why is it needed?

Comment: Because the transaction is at the queue manager level and not the message level.  Also, you should never rely on something else guessing when an action needs to be done.  i.e. If you open it, close it.  If you start a transaction, then YOU control when it is committed or backed-out.

Comment: There could be a small delay before MSDTC commits a transaction. Do you close your application immediately after the above method returns? What happens if you insert a small "sleep" before the method returns?

Comment: @Roger by having an explicit `Using...End Using` statement for my `TransactionScope` object, as far as I am aware I am doing that.

Comment: @Shashi, no, it doesn't matter how long I wait before closing the program, the messages just sit in limbo until I do so. I suspect there's an ambient transaction somewhere that's getting in the way

Comment: ...- but I can't see how. I've tried setting the `TransactionScopeOptions` to `RequiresNew` (so it doesn't subscribe to any ambient transaction), but it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a MQSeries perspective, .NET TransactionScope is an externally coordinated transaction. MQ will only participate in an externally coordinated transaction under certain circumstances.

e.g. you might find that you need an MQ Commit when testing in a client environment, but not on your production server.

For more information look at this:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q003570_.htm

and

http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=49148

and the IBM red books (however dated) are always a good read:

http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247012.pdf

Comment: Programfiles/WebsphereMQ/tools/dotnet/samples/cs/base/SimpleXAPut/SimpleXAPut.cs is an IBM-provided example that uses the TransactionScope object from .NET - so it must be possible to use it...

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: The second link in your answer says "Only if running serverside, or with the ETC (Extended Transactional Client)". From what I can see, ETC should be included in 7.5 and so it should work?

Comment: With respect Simon, this is now classic Stack Overflow mission creep. Your   original question was basically "how can I make this work". I provided a simple correct answer to this, which is, of course, not the answer you want to hear. Now you are asking "why". "Why" depends on a whole number of environmental factors - software levels, configuration parameters etc. This is not what Stack Overflow is about. However, if you open a  new question providing detailed environmental and configuration information then I will attempt to help.

Comment: No offence taken, I understand. Which information would you need?

Comment: None intended. I would be happy to try to recreate this (it may take me a couple of days). Basic stuff like how you are running it desktop / laptop / server ... windows versions, MQ version and Visual Studio version. Any anecdotal information that you think might be relevant (e.g. did you install it yourself or did someone else do it) etc. Regards.

Comment: Sorry, I'm busy on other stuff at the moment; and on holiday from this evening. I'll post the question after the holidays, and comment here - but of course I won't expect you to answer if you're not free after so long a gap.

Comment: That's fine ...I'll try to help.